# Use echo result in a if check in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to unset the folders which have two '_' characters in their name from my array.But I am getting permission denied error. Can you please help me to fix it? Here is my script and its output:

```
#!/bin/sh

ALLVERSION=(/dir/test*)
echo "first version:"
for ((i=0; i<${#ALLVERSION[@]}; i++)); do
    if [[ `${ALLVERSION[i]} | grep -o '_' | wc -l` -eq 2 ]]; then
    unset ALLVERSION[i] 
    fi 
done
echo "last version:"
for f in "${ALLVERSION[@]}"; do
   echo "$f"
done
```

result:

```
first version:
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test03_01.txt: Permission denied
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test03_01_01.txt: Permission denied
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test03_01_04.txt: Permission denied
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test03_04.txt: Permission denied
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test03_05_04.txt: Permission denied
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test04_01_04.txt: Permission denied
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test05_00.txt: Permission denied
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test05_01.txt: Permission denied
countcharacter.sh: line 6: /dir/test06_01.txt: Permission denied
last version:
/dir/test03_01.txt
/dir/test03_01_01.txt
/dir/test03_01_04.txt
/dir/test03_04.txt
/dir/test03_05_04.txt
/dir/test04_01_04.txt
/dir/test05_00.txt
/dir/test05_01.txt
/dir/test06_01.txt
```

Comment: if [[ ` echo ${ALLVERSION[i]} | grep -o '_' | wc -l` -eq 2 ]]; then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `echo ${ALLVERSION[i]}` before piping it to `grep`:

```
if [[ `echo ${ALLVERSION[i]} | grep -o '_' | wc -l` -eq 2 ]]; then
```

Without `echo` the file stored in `${ALLVERSION[i]` is executed and its output is passed to `grep`.

As a side note, for command substitutions you should use the `$(yourcommand)` syntax that is recommended as more readable over the use of backticks `` `yourcommand` ``.

Answer (score 1):

Alongside this useful [SLePort's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242952/5291015), you can achieve your requirement with native `bash` tools alone and not fork any third party tools.

```
echo "first version:"
for ((i=0; i<${#ALLVERSION[@]}; i++)); do  

    # Strip every character that is not '_', so "${#count}" will be 2 for
    # those lines containing two '_'
    count="${ALLVERSION[i]//[!_]/}"

    if (( "${#count}" == 2 )); then
        unset ALLVERSION[i]
    fi
done

echo "last version:"
for f in "${ALLVERSION[@]}"; do
   echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: @SLePort: Thanks for the feedback, also good if you could recommend the `$()` syntax over the outdated, error prone `` syntax

Answer (score 1):

You rarely need `grep` unless you are processing every line of a file. For single lines of input, use `bash`'s regular expression operator.

```
if [[ ${ALLVERSION[i]} =~ /dir/test_[^_]*_[^_]* ]]; then
    unset ALLVERSION[i] 
fi
```

or use an extended pattern match:

```
# If you are using an older version of bash, you'll need
# to set the extglob option first.
# shopt -s extglob
if [[ ${ALLVERSION[i]} == /dir/test_*(!(_))_*(!(_)) ]]; then
    unset ALLVERSION[i] 
fi
```